# Combine two Font Awesome icons

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome, stacked

I'm trying to combine two Font Awesome icons, to create a stack. I'm trying to merge `fa-calendar` and `fa-clock-o` icons. This because, I need an icon for date-time.

So, in order to combine them, I tried this:

HTML

```
<span class="icon-stack">
   <i class="fa fa-calendar icon-stack-3x"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-clock-o icon-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

CSS

```
.icon-stack {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 5em;
  line-height: 4em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.icon-stack-1x,
.icon-stack-2x,
.icon-stack-3x {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.icon-stack-1x {
  line-height: inherit;
}
.icon-stack-2x {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.icon-stack-3x {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

This is what I get as a result.

[image]

But, I want to bring a little bit to right. I don't know how to do that? What can I do to bring it a bit towards right?

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/stacking-icons and then just play with left and top properties

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, as you have done your own CSS for position you just need to set the `text-align` to `right`, like this:

```
.icon-stack-3x {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/exg492n2/)

---

The problem is, that doesn't look great. So here are a couple of alternatives in case they are of use to you: [Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/exg492n2/1/), [Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/exg492n2/2/)

Comment: This works, how can I make it more clear? ie Looks a bit nasty, to make it look good. Any help with that?

Comment: @duddosai: Yeah I did try but problem is they don't have a clock icon that isn't transparent (which is the problem). Why don't you try a different calendar? [maybe something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/exg492n2/1/) though I did use absolute position which can be problematic sometimes, especially with different browsers. You could try using the built-in stacking classes instead, [and do it simple like this](http://jsfiddle.net/exg492n2/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can either make clock align right or padding-left by adding a new class
Please see the below code:

```css
.icon-stack {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 2em;
      height: 5em;
      line-height: 4em;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .icon-stack-1x,
    .icon-stack-2x,
    .icon-stack-3x {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .icon-stack-1x {
      line-height: inherit;
    }
    .icon-stack-2x {
      font-size: 1.5em;
    }
    .icon-stack-3x {
      font-size: 2em;
    }
.right_align { padding-left:5px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<span class="icon-stack">
   <i class="fa fa-calendar icon-stack-3x"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-clock-o icon-stack-1x right_align"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: This helps, but I want it to look good, like it must be clear. What can be done?